# Obtener altura de una imagen en un arreglo

Tags: jquery

Quiero conseguir el `height` de varias imágenes que están como hijos de sus respectivos contenedores, intenté obtener todos los elementos padre y luego obtener el elemento hijo con `find('img')`, pero no consigo hacer que imprima el `height` de cada imagen, intenté con un `for` pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

> (index):19 Uncaught TypeError: cuadro[i].height is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost/portafolio/:19:43)
>       at j (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2:27136)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2:27949)
>       at Function.ready (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2:29783)
>       at HTMLDocument.K (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2:30128)
>       at :2:479
>       at HTMLDocument.f.string.e.function.b.(anonymous function) (eval at exec_fn (:2:27), :52:92)
>       at :2:479
>       at c (:2:324)
>       at :2:479

Si le quito el `for` me devuelve solamente el `height` de la primera imágen, aquí el último código que probé:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      var cuadro = $('.singleItem');
      var imagen = $(cuadro).find("img");
      console.log(imagen.height());
});
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Lato;
    background: url(https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/perspectiva-rectangulo-en-posicion-diagonal_318-69634.jpg) repeat #FFF;
    color: #404040;
}

.singleItem{
    width: 100%;
    height: 325px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(https://image.prntscr.com/image/f5lAtzzEQpW154NswSnJ-g.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    position: relative;
}
.sliderIt{
    width: 100%;
    height: 296px;
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sliderIt img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transition: all ease 6s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 6s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 6s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 6s;
    -o-transition: all ease 6s;
}

.singleItem:hover .sliderIt img{
    margin-top: -1614px;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px){
    .singleItem:hover .sliderIt img {
        margin-top: -702px;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="singleItem">
<div class="sliderIt">
<img class="img" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/no-thinking-allowed-symbol-7026534.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="singleItem">
<div class="sliderIt">
<img class="img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1b/f4/8c/1bf48c294196634ea3c762bd567f562f.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿Donde está el `for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer referencia en un ciclo como un for o each *(como mi ejemplo)* deberá seleccionar el elemento con JQuery de forma tradicional `$(elemento)` para luego recién poder acceder a `height()` ,

¿Por qué es necesario esto ?

En el ejemplo que muestra selecciona el `heigth` del elemento qué ya es una instancia de `jQuery` y en un `for` no lo es. Al iterar se convierte en un elemento del `DOM` simplemente.

**Resultado final**

```js
$(function() {
    //Each
    var imagenes = $('.singleItem').find("img").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).height());
    });
    // For Tradicional
    var imagenes = $('.singleItem').find("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
        console.log($(imagenes[i]).height());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="singleItem">
        <div class="sliderIt">
            <img class="img" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/no-thinking-allowed-symbol-7026534.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="singleItem">
        <div class="sliderIt">
            <img class="img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1b/f4/8c/1bf48c294196634ea3c762bd567f562f.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias!, no estaba colocando tipo $(element), sino directo el nombre que le puse a la variable.

Comment: @AndySamuelAlvarado si , recuerde que para acceder a funciones de Jquery debe tener antes una instancia de este. si no, no funcionará. Saludos.